# Springboot project with gradle is failing with error - Multiple bindings

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Spring boot project is failing on `run` and giving below errors. What is causing this error and  How can i prevent.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/z00381z/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.1/4b41b53a3a2d299ce381a69d165381ca19f62912/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/z00381z/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/ccedfbacef4a6515d2983e3f89ed753d5d4fb665/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

**Gradle File**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "https://binrepo.mycompany.com/artifactory/platform" }
    maven { url "https://binrepo.mycompany.com/artifactory/maven-central" }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.mycompany.platform:platform-connector-gradle:1.1.4"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "com.mycompany.platform.connector.spring-boot"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

mainClassName = "com.mycompany.learnattargetuser.Main"

version = "0.0.1"

distTar.version = ""

dependencies{
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
}
```

Comment: what version of SpringBoot are you using?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti It is 2.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noticed that the conflict comes from two jars, named **logback.jar** and **log4j-slf4j-impl-.jar**.
Now choose the one you want to ignore.
I'll ignore slf4j-log4j12.

In gardle

```
 configurations.all {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
```

or ignore logback.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```